Mesomeric Effect in -CH=CH2 and -N=O
I'm confused in the mesomeric effect for 2 compounds, specifically -CH=CH2 and -N=O...
Firstly -CH=CH2 it is supposed to show -M mesomeric effect... but my chemistry teacher said that it can show both -M and +M effects which i couldn't figure out...
Secondly -N=O I believed that it would show -M effect cause a partial positive charge forms on nitrogen, making it electron withdrawing...However again my teacher said that since nitrogen had a lone pair, it can show both -M and +M effects...

welcome to Chemistry SE. I would recommend you go through Organic Chemistry by Paula Yurkanis Bruice and read the sections on resonance structures and resonance patterns.

That's a relative term. Say the -CH=CH2 is joined to another -CH=CH2 then it can not only show +M but also -M. As for NO, it has a lone pair which can delocalize into a π bond showing +M and also shows -M effect because it has a π bond.
